# How to improve LIKE query with multiple where methods

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this query,

```
User.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%").where(group: "student").limit(10)
```

and I have this sneaking suspicion that I can improve it somehow, mainly allowing on one where method instead of two but any attempt results in the sql query not recognizing the group field. So far the above works but I want to know if this can be improved or not and how.

Also, should I worry about having multiple where methods in a query besides for the aesthetic look?

Comment: you shouldn't worry about a chain of `#where` calls - the translation into SQL will take much less time than the database query itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code you have is fine and is more readable than combining the calls to `where`.  As pointed out by other commenters/answers, having multiple calls to `where` will not impact the total speed of the db query.

If you're wondering how to change the query to a single `where` call, try the following

```
User.where('name LIKE ? AND group = ?', "%#{term}%", 'student').limit(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for showing what it would look like as one query. I was curious how it would end up looking. I think I'll stick with the multiple where's though, they do look better.

Answer (score 1):

The multiple where's are not going to have any noticeable impact on the performance. The DB is only ever being hit once.

Queries with "LIKE" are inherently slow.